# Determining AM or PM in user time zone for UTC value

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have a UTC value and I need to determine if the time component of the value is AM or PM in user's time zone.

For example, if the value is `July 21, 2017 16:00 UTC` and user's time zone is US Pacific time zone, this would be a morning hour i.e. AM.

Comment: Parse into a `Date` object, then do `getHours()` on it. If it's greater than 11, it's PM.

Comment: check out moment.js it can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this function to get AM/PM value, you can alter the script as per your needs (as currently it display only AM/PM hours)

```
function formatAMPM(date) {
  var hours = date.getHours();
  var minutes = date.getMinutes();
  var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';
  hours = hours % 12;
  hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
  minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0'+minutes : minutes;
  var strTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + ampm;
  return strTime;
}

console.log(formatAMPM(new Date('July 21, 2017 16:00 UTC'))); // will show AM/PM value
```

Note: as javascript converts all dates to your local timezone, the values shown will be as per your system time.